# Is this a good correction for "our-find-if" at Graham's OnLisp page 23 errata?

Tags: common-lisp, on-lisp

Paul Graham's ['On Lisp' errata page](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisperrata.html%20%22'On%20Lisp'%20errata%20web%20page) states:

> p. 23. our-find-if would recurse infinitely if no element matches. Caught by Markus Triska.

The function definition as shown in the book is:

```
(defun our-find-if (fn lst)
    (if (funcall fn (car lst))
        (car lst)
        (our-find-if fn (cdr lst))))
```

And here is my probably poor fix for it:

```
(defun our-find-if (fn lst)
    (if (funcall fn (car lst))
        (car lst)
        (if (cdr lst)
            (our-find-if fn (cdr  lst))
            nil)))
```

Is this correct? Is my version of 'our-find-if' still tail recursive? (I think so...)

Better alternatives welcome.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK, and it is tail recursive.

I would propose the following changes, though:

- use standard indentation (2 spaces for a body)
- use `cond` instead of nested `if`s
- use non-abbreviated variable names, and `predicate` for a function that returns a boolean
- use `endp` to test for the end of the list

*update:* first test for end of list, thanks to Paulo Madeira

It looks like this then:

```
(defun our-find-if (predicate list)
  (cond ((endp list)
         nil)
        ((funcall predicate (car list))
         (car list))
        (t
         (our-find-if predicate (cdr list)))))
```

Comment: Actually, you should test for the end of the list first, otherwise `predicate` will be called with `nil` for an empty list, which it seems is not the purpose, e.g. `(our-find-if 'evenp '())`  will signal an error.

Comment: I understand you're referring to my own version so it was not really OK. In my discharge I must say this flaw was already present in Graham's one :-)